# How to get images from server using C#, ASP.NET Core MVC and Xamarin Forms on Android?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working with C#, Xamarin Forms Android and ASP.NET Core MVC. Basically what I'm doing is pass a json that contains a number that is linked to images in my ASP.NET Core MVC project. I'm trying with this code:

C# Xamarin Forms android code:

```
private string urlImages = "myWebUrl/getImgs";

public async Task getImages()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
            var baseAddress = urlImages;

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                            {"var1", Preferences.Get("VAR", "Default")},
                    };

            var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            var contentData = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync(baseAddress, contentData);
            var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            await DisplayAlert("Result", res, "OK");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

C# ASP.NET Core MVC code:

```
[Route("getImgs")]
private List<Image> traerImagenesEntrega([FromBody] dynamic jsonObject)
{
    JsonElement entrega_tr = jsonObject.GetProperty("var1");

    List<PedidoViewModel> list = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
    List<Image> listaImagenes = new List<Image>();
    list = VerEntrega(entrega_tr.ToString());

    foreach (var entrega in list)
    {
        var imageResult = Image.Load("wwwroot/" + entrega.getPathImagen());
        listaImagenes.Add(imageResult);
    }

    return listaImagenes;
}
```

This is an image about what i have in the variable response in my C# Xamarin Forms Android:

[image]

Basically I'm getting the images. But I can't put them in a list.
How could I get these images an save them in a list?

Thank you very much!

----------------- **UPDATE** -----------------

C# ASP.NET Core MVC code:

```
[Route("getImgs")]
    public List<byte[]> traerImagenesEntregaAsync([FromBody] dynamic jsonObject)
    {
        JsonElement entrega_tr = jsonObject.GetProperty("var1");
        List<PedidoViewModel> list = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
        List<byte[]> li = new List<byte[]>();
        list = VerEntrega(entrega_tr.ToString());
        foreach (var entrega in list)
        {
            li.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("wwwroot/" + entrega.getPathImagen()));
        }

        return li;
    }
```

So, now I am returning a list of `byte[]`. How could I get in my C# xamarin forms android app this list? I understand that I need to do a `File.WriteAllBytes()` to get the images but I don't know where are the byte arrays.

I left here an image of what I get

Image:
[image]

Comment: you are returning the serialized Image object.  Instead you either need to return a list of urls to the images, or a byte[] containing the actual image data

Comment: Thank you @Jason ! Now I updated my question. How could I do what I wrote there? because I don't find the `Byte[]` that I'm returning. Thank you again!

Comment: Returning a list of urls would be much simpler

Comment: Yeah I know. But what I need is to display the images that comes from the server in my mobile application. Is there anyway to do it with urls?

Comment: Yes.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#download-images